# Realtime multi_line graph updates at decent performance

Tags: python, bokeh, graphing

I'm currently using Bokeh to present a `multi_line` plot, that has several static lines and one line, that is live updated. This runs fine with only few lines but, depending on the resolution of the lines (usually 2000-4000 points per line), the refreshing rate drops significantly when having 50+ lines in the plot. The CPU usage of the browser is pretty high at that moment.

This is how the the plot is initialized and the live update is triggered:

```py
    figure_opts = dict(plot_width=750,
                        plot_height=750,
                        x_range=(0, dset_size),
                        y_range=(0, np.iinfo(dtype).max),
                        tools='pan,wheel_zoom')

    line_opts = dict(
        line_width=5, line_color='color', line_alpha=0.6,
        hover_line_color='color', hover_line_alpha=1.0,
        source=profile_lines
    )

    profile_plot = figure(**figure_opts)
    profile_plot.toolbar.logo = None
    multi_line_plot = profile_plot.multi_line(xs='x', ys='y', **line_opts)
    profile_plot.xaxis.axis_label = "x"
    profile_plot.yaxis.axis_label = "y"

    ds = multi_line_plot.data_source

    def update_live_plot():
        random_arr = np.random.random_integers(65535 * (i % 100) / (100 + 100 / 4), 65535 * (i % 100 + 1) / 100, (2048))
        profile = random_arr.astype(np.uint16)
        if profile is not None:
            profile_lines["x"][i] = x
            profile_lines["y"][i] = profile
            profile_lines["color"][i] = Category20_20[0]
            ds.data = profile_lines

    doc.add_periodic_callback(update_live_plot, 100)
```

Is there any way to make this better performing?
Is it, for example, possible to only update the one line, that needs to get updated, instead of `ds.data = profile_lines`?

**Edit:** The one line that needs to be updated has to be updated in its full length. I.e. I'm not streaming data at one end, but instead I have a full new set of 2000-4000 values and want to show those, instead of the old *live* line.
Currently the *live* line is the element at `i` in the arrays in the `profile_lines` dictionary.

Comment: More detail is needed. Are you trying to update these lines without changing their length? Or are you trying to stream new data to ends of the individual lines? Or? (I ask, because it makes a difference)

Comment: I hope I clarified that now, that I'm updating the line in total at a constant length. I'm not streaming data at one end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in luck, updating a single line with all new elements *while keeping the same length* is something that can be accomplished with the CDS `patch` method. (Streaming would not help here, since streaming to the end of a CDS for a `multi_line` means adding an entire new line, and the other case of streaming to the end of each sub-line does not have a good solution at all.)

There is a [`patch_app.py` example](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/howto/patch_app.py) in the repository that shows how to use `patch` to update one line of a `multi_line`. The example only updates a single point in the line, but it's possible to update the entire line at once using slices:

```
source.patch({ 'ys' : [([i, slice(None)], new_y)]})
```

That will update the ith line in `source.data['ys']`, as long as `new_y` has the same length as the old line.